# C++ template method, changing the behavior based on the template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a c++ template method.
Below is a sample code demonstrating what I want to do within the method.

```
template<class T>
void method(T value) {
    // This string should change based on type T 
    char *str = "Int" or "Float" or .. ;   
    ...
    ...
    std::cout << value << " is of type " << str << std::cout;
}
```

Basically, the behavior (the string value in this example) of the method will change based on the type T.
How could I do this with template?

Comment: Do you really need this to be a template method? You might just be able to use some non-templated overload methods.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specialize your template over different types. If you start with a base case:

```
template <class T>
void method(T value);
```

You can then declare different behavior for any specific value of `T`:

```
template <>
void method<int>(int value) {
  // special behavior
}
```

And so forth. But since only the input type of your function is changing, you really don't need templates in this case! You can just overload your function with different argument types:

```
void method(int T);
void method(float T);
void method(void* T);
```

**EDIT**: Using template specialization to get the name of a type and use it in another function template:

```
template <class T>
std::string type_to_string();

template <>
std::string type_to_string<int>() {
  return "int";
}

template <>
std::string type_to_string<float>() {
  return "float";
}


template <class T>
some_other_function(T value) {
  std::cout << value << " is a " << type_to_string<T>() << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, you can still do this without templates:

```
std::string type_to_string(int) {
  return "int";
}

some_other_function(int value) {
  std::cout << value << " is a " << type_to_string(value) << std::endl;
}
```

If you had to do some complex type-level computation, I'd suggest using templates. But here, I think you can accomplish what you want rather nicely without them. Either way, the idiomatic way (with or without templates) is to split your function into its different natural pieces.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use the template was because then I could share some code portions (for example, the printing statement at the end). But with overloading, I have to write the entire functions for each type. Am I missing something?

Comment: Mmm, I see. You could write a function `typeToString<T>()` specialized over the common types, which would return a string corresponding to `T`. Then, you could use that in your original function template.

Comment: Factor out the shared code that you anticipate repeating in each overloaded method and place it in a separate 'utility' method. Then just call that 'utility' method in each overloaded method.

Comment: Yeah. That seems to work for me (both of your answers). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head a couple of ways:

1. Perhaps T could have a method that returns the appropriate string, and all your T's provide that method.

Then you can say:

char *str = T.getTheAppropriateString();

1. RTTI and dynamic_cast. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information.

Comment: But... I think really that Jonathan Sterling has a better answer (ie simpler solution) than mine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much and how often the behavior changes.  If
the behavior is different for each type, you might consider not
using a template at all, just standard overloading.  If the
behavior is usually the same, but completely different for one
or two cases, you can use explicit specialization for these
cases.  If most of the behavior is always the same, but there is
one small part that varies, you can either factor that part out
into an overloaded function, or use a traits class:

```
template <typename T> CustomBehavior;

template <typename T>
void
function( T value )
{
    //  ...
    CustomBehavior<T>::specialized(...);
    //  ...
}
```